# DRF Saving nested object and updating the other

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to update entity and simultaneously create the other one using DRF and nested serializers. Both entities are connected with one-to-one relation with common "root"

My models looks like:

```
class Root(Model):
    ...
class Node1(Model):
    root = OneToOneField(Root)
class Node2(Model):
    root = OneToOneField(Root)
```

In my scenario entity of Root and Node1 exists and I want to update node1 and create node2 in one HTTP request.

I tried use serializers like this:

```
class Node1Serializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Node1
        fields = '__all__'

class Node2Serializer(ModelSerializer): 
    node1 = Node1Serializer(partial=True) # here I want update just few fields of node1
    class Meta(object):
        model = Node2
        fields = '__all__'
```

I'm sending data by post like:

```
{root: 1, entity2_param1: "...", "node1": {root: 1, id:1, entity1_param1: "..."}}
```

In response I get that root must be unique. What is correct approach for this task?

Answer (score 0):

The body of your http request would look something like this:

```
{  
   "node_1":{
            "attribute_one":"attribute_one_data",
            "attribute_two":"attribute_two_data",
            ...
            "node_two": {
                        "attribute_one":"attribute_one_data",
                        ...
                 }
}
```

Then in node one's serializer update method you'd do the following:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # update any node_one fields you want
    instance.attribute_one = validated_data.get('attribute_one', instance.attribute_one)
        ....
    # check if node_two data was passed into request
    if 'node_two' in validated_data:
            data = validated_data.pop('node_two')
            if data:
                Node_Two.objects.create(root=root, **data)
```

The one piece that's missing is you'd have to pass an instance of root into the update method. You can do that a few different ways. If you need help there let me know.